# Remove Type From values_list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Wanted to remove the guard from the query set.**

Guard is a many-to-many field in the table InstituteGate

```
def delete(self, request):
        institute = self.request.query_params.get("institute", None)
        data = request.data
        queryset = InstituteGate.objects.filter(
            institute=institute, name=data["gate"])
        for i in queryset:
            guards = i.guards.all().values_list('id', flat=True,)
            print(guards)
            if data["guard"] in guards:
                i.guards.remove(data["guard"])
        return Response("Succesfully Removed Guard From gate", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

printing guard gives

```
<QuerySet [UUID('dfca4bbf-e823-4888-af6b-7fc6438c697e'), UUID('62663459a-ff71-4f5e-86c6-36405b611859'), UUID('sd52sds-2825-43ac-91b2-3cccae48b4ab'), UUID('adadss55d-4a7d-4e31-850b-f5a55beb75ce')]>
```

But I need

```
<QuerySet [('dfca4bbf-e823-4888-af6b-7fc6438c697e'), ('62663459a-ff71-4f5e-86c6-36405b611859'), ('sd52sds-2825-43ac-91b2-3cccae48b4ab'), ('adadss55d-4a7d-4e31-850b-f5a55beb75ce')]>
```

What to do??

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: both the response looks similar i guess

Comment: Actually i.guards.remove(data["guard"]) is not working even if the UUID is present.

Comment: You will get the UUID Object from DBif you just want to convert in `uuid` then use `[str(guard) for guards in guards]`

Comment: If you wanted to remove from M2M then you have to pass the object, not ID, so better to do only `guards = i.guards.all()` then use the `remove` by passing the `guard` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast and textfield in django to overcome this or simple for loop.
Try this cast by importing in your project.

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
```

inside your queryset for loop try this approach

```
guards = guards.objects.annotate(str_id=Cast('id', 
output_field=TextField())).values_list('str_id', flat=True)
```

Hope this might help
Or you can also try simple for loop

guards = [str(g) for g in guards]